# Why does Tor only work on TCP?

Tags: encryption

Is it because of the nature of it's encryption protocol? I'm assuming there are other reasons as well, but I have not been able to find any information about it.

Comment: Read the [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TransportIPnotTCP).

Answer (score -1):

Basically it's about the main difference between TCP and UDP - udp packets are fire-and-forget ones, but tcp's are much more strict and simple to handle. The working with UDP as a transport for Tor *itself* has it's uses, but I'm sure that it will be implemented in a future: there're too many bonuses in doing so that it simply can be ignored. If you want to transport UDP for your hidden service, for example, - just use OpenVPN! TCP was the "first and most universal/wide" choice, and it's better implement a single feature, but good - rather than ten of them, but badly: we've seen the Microsoft approach on features, it stinks :)

IMHO: - this is my very personal opinion:

- Privacy concerns in Tor FAQ about non-tcp packets revealing OS are ridiculous, this can be handled "not so hard"
- The "DNS resolver excuse" is an issue that must be fixed *regardless of IP support*, even if it will be still just TCP only supported

Comment: "Privacy concerns in Tor FAQ about non-tcp packets revealing OS are ridiculous, this can be handled "not so hard"" <- [Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) in action.

Comment: Also you're wrong re the difference between tcp/udp in that respect but you already demonstrated you don't understand that aspect of networking in previous answers.

Comment: @canonizingironize You should clarify yourself a word "basically" - just to stop sounding like a joke, man :) Pehaps you're better cool down and actually read and try to understand what I mean *in a whole answer*, not cherrypicking a separate words and sentences out-of-context. Thanks!